# How to start a Google+ Hangout from android/mobile phone?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

So Google just released a new version of the Google+ app that has Hangout support. **But how do I start a Hangout on my mobile phone?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bummer but currently you can't. You can only join a hangout from the phone. From the [Google+ help](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1669210&topic=1248781):

On Hangouts for mobile, you have the ability to:

- Join a hangout

You can't currently:

- Start a hangout
- Invite people to join a hangout

(The January 2012 update of the Google+ app changed this, however.)

Answer (score 7):

That is actually not true.  As of yesterday you can.  Here are the instructions.

Make sure you have updated to the newest version of the G+ app. You should have version 2.3.1.242969 that came out yesterday.

From there you need to go to messenger and find the person you want to hangout with and send them a message. Once you send them a message you will see a hangout icon appear in the top right corner. See [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/12/19/coming-soon-ability-to-start-a-google-hangout-from-your-mobile-device/) for more information.

Comment: Great that they have now added this. I'll try to remove my answer.

Comment: But when I start a hangout on my phone, how do I access it from a desktop web browser? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24032/access-old-google-hangout-from-web-browser