# Why doesn't my phone support Google + hangouts?

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-talk, video-calling, google-hangouts

I have Motorola xt502 phone which is a Commtiva z71 variant, running android 2.3.7 CM7.1.

I was wondering what is limiting the hangout feature on my phone.

Is it because it has arm v6 cpu, the missing front facing camera or memory constraints? GTalk video is also not available on my phone.

Any info? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't support? You can not start a hangout from mobile you can only join: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14546/how-to-start-a-google-hangout-from-android-mobile-phone

Comment: @flow ya i cant join even.

Comment: What message do you get when you try to join?

Comment: Most likely it's the lack of front camera for both G+ Hangouts and GTalk w/video.

Answer (score 2):

As Chahk mentioned: It's the lack of a front facing camera.

But there are [ways to fake a front facing camera](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=17767832#post17767832), so that you can join hangouts.